# Improving Position Sync Bandwidth Usage in a Multiplayer Game

Tags: unity, android, multiplayer

This is the class i use to sync position between clients in a multiplayer top-down 2D shooter game:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MovementUpdateClass
    {
        public int MessageTime {get; set;}

        public Vector2Serializer PosXY = new Vector2Serializer();
        public Vector2Serializer VelXY = new Vector2Serializer();
        public float RotZ {get; set;}

        public MovementUpdateClass(int messageTime, Vector2 posXY, Vector2 velXY, float rotZ)
        {
            MessageTime = messageTime;
            PosXY.V2 = posXY;
            VelXY.V2 = velXY;
            RotZ = rotZ;
        }
    }
```

Any advices about how to improve & optimize it so it spends less bandwidth for both sender and receivers?

Thanks.